# How capture Web Push Notifications using mitmproxy?

Tags: web-push, mitmproxy

I want to capture Web Push Notifications using mitmproxy. I tried with several configurations but every time I activate the mitmproxy in my OS the Web Push Notifications stop showing in the OS. The rest of the navigation is good, it is just that Wen Push Notifications are not being shown by the OS.

I was using https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload_demo.html to do the testing.

Any idea of how to configure mitmproxy to catch Web Push Notifications?

Comment: WebPush notifications are shown by the web browser, not the OS. hence first you have to make sure your used web browser works with mitmproxy.

Comment: @Robert Actually they are shown by the OS too. It is the browsers who capture them, but the OS shows them too. In Windows 10 for example you can see recent web push notifications.

Comment: Windows as the OS shows each and every notification (sent to it's notification API) in it's UI but the notification belongs to the web browser. No web browser no notification. Hence you need to configure the web browser only to use mitmproxy for capturing web push notifications.

Comment: @Robert Correct, that was what I did and notifications stop being sent to the OS and I didn't get anything in mitmproxy what makes me think that some way mitmproxy broke something. I just mentioned the OS part as a way to illustrate that notif stop working.